# Problem with place of commands in a regex

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, windows-10

The following code works apparently well (so far).

```
$fic = 'G1.txt' 
$SS  = 'G2.txt'
(Get-Content -Path $fic) -replace '^_Tc\*.+|^_|\\>.+|^\s*$' | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | Set-   Content -Path $SS
```

For this input,

```
_Tc*\^{}ctl-spr\\°{tab\ec\-chargement\>\spill
_av \> falstaff\\
_age \> arément et act pratig\\
_AARDC \> amplitude font\\
_Tc*\^{}ctl-spr\\°}tab\ec\- ab\>\spill







_brim\> plomb\\
_zetrans \> fuil\\
_atrim \> déchargement\\
```

I get this output,

```
av 
age 
AARDC 
brim
zetrans 
atrim
```

which is according to the regex (I hope it is anyway). However when I replace `'^_Tc\*.+|^_|\\>.+|^\s*$'` by `'^_|\\>.+|^Tc\*.+|^\s*$'` here is the output I get.

```
Tc*\^{}ctl-spr\\°{tab\ec\-chargement
av 
age 
AARDC 
Tc*\^{}ctl-spr\\°}tab\ec\- ab
brim
zetrans 
atrim
```

I believed that since the undersore is removed by the 1rst alternative, then it shouldn't appear before "Tc*".
Could someone point out the principle involved and how to make the second code work?

Comment: `^` anchors the pattern to the start of the line, so `^_` is matching the locations where `_` is in the first position in the line. `^Tc` will never match any of the lines because `T` is never the first character.

Comment: @ctwheels That's my problem: I don't understand why it's not the first character since the first alternative  removes the first everywhere it (as I understand that). Does that mean that a removal leaves a white space?

Comment: It's only replacing once, not in a loop. The replace function doesn't loop over itself, it runs once. It replaces as much as possible (which is why it replaces other sections of the string) but it doesn't replace, then check the altered string and continue replacing, it gets all the positions that matched (the starting and ending points of each match), then replaces those substrings with your replacement string.

Comment: Yes, the pieces and order has changed   so as now it takes 2 or more replacements from each alterred string. Do it in a sequence of replacements and it should come out the same.

Comment: Also, this `^\s*$` should not be optional.in the alternation list. Btw, whats wrong with the first regex ?

Comment: @x15 I removed `^\s*$` in both codes and everything is as before, so apparently it is not needed. I thought it would remove white space lines, as that's what I needed. They are still being removed  but I don't see why. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: The empty or whitespace lines are not removed by the regex, but by the `Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }` clause. BTW. I see you have replaced all quote characters by curly 'smart-quotes' `’`. These may look nice in Word, but can play havoc in code. Rule of thumb: **Never use curly quotes in code** but replace them with straight ones `'`.